# Can tf.keras.layers.xx be used independently from tf.keras.Sequential or Model?

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

In Tensorflow, many functions from some modules have been deprecated. Those from `tf.keras.layers` have been recommended. The [tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model) provide examples of the usage of them by associating them with either `tf.keras.Sequential (Sequential)` or `tf.keras.Model (Model)`. I want to know whether it's possible to use some classes in `tf.keras.layers (e.g., Dense, Conv1D, etc.)` without using `Sequential` or `Model`.

Previously the following was used in my code:

```
gru = tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(d)
states, output = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(gru, inputs)
```

As both `tf.contrib.rnn` and `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` have been deprecated, I want to know if I can replace them with the following commands without adding `Sequential` or `Model` in the code.

```
gru = tf.keras.layers.GRUCell(d)
states, output = keras.layers.RNN(gru)(inputs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know whether it's possible to use some classes in tf.keras.layers (e.g., Dense, Conv1D, etc.) without using Sequential or Model.

Yes, sure it is. We can just 'call' the layer directly by doing something like this, for example:

```py
layer_example = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2,input_shape=(-1,24))
example_tensor = tf.random.uniform(shape=(2, 24))
layer_example(example_tensor)
```

Note that we first create an instance of the layer class with `tf.keras.layers.Dense` then later *call* that instance with `layer_example(example_tensor)`

We can also (of course) extend this to the GRU example. Something like this:

```
example_tensor = tf.random.uniform(shape=(2, 24, 12))
gru = tf.keras.layers.GRUCell(2)
states, output = tf.keras.layers.RNN(gru)(example_tensor)
```